# Select from table using multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
| id | market | source | event |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| 1  |   1    |   1    |   1   |
| 2  |   1    |   2    |   1   |
| 3  |   2    |   1    |   1   |
| 4  |   3    |   1    |   2   |
| 5  |   1    |   3    |   1   |
```

I want to be able to select rows where (market = 1 AND event = 1) and also where (market = 3 AND event = 2). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you heard of the `where` clause?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the select you need:

```
select * from `table` where  (market = 1 AND event = 1) or (market = 3 AND event = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> where (market = 1 AND event = 1) ALSO where (market = 3 AND event = 2)
>   above can be converted to

```
WHERE (market = 1 AND event = 1)  OR (market = 3 AND event = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace t_table with your table name here:

```
Select * from t_table where (market = 1 and event = 1) or (market = 3 and event = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT source 
FROM tableA 
WHERE (market = 1 AND event = 1)  OR 
      (market = 3 AND event = 2) 
GROUP BY source 
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2;
```